# ASIHTTPRequest and background download

Tags: iphone, delegates, background, download, asihttprequest

I was planning to use ASIHttprequest to download an mp3 file.
i will need to use queues because there can be multiple simultaneous downloads.

I saw that you can use

```
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
```

if you want to support background execution... 
If the file completes in the background, how can i handle this?

will the delegates be called anyway?
can i make one of those notification badges from the delegate if the app was in background whenn the delegate was called?

PS: I AM on iOS4, and background exec is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requestFinished` method should still be called before the `endBackgroundTask:` is called on the download; however, to ensure the functionality you want gets executed (a notification badge or something), you should use a `UIBackgroundTask`.

Basically the idea is that you create a new background task and use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` in the delegate finished method and then do whatever you want in the background task (see the apple dev guide about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Make sure you call `endBackgroundTask` on your task after you are done!

Comment: UIBackgroundTask mandates a Synchronous operation, doesn't it?
I need to show the progress of the download as it is happening. Will making the operation synchronous make it impossible to get delegate notifications about the progress?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to show the user the progress while the app is in the background. I was talking about using the UIBackgroundTask to notify the user the download is done, if the app finishes the download while its in the background. You would still use ASIHTTP to download/monitor the queue.

Comment: Looks like I do not have the expertise to understand that answer completely. :(
what I understand from what you said is that the (ASIhttp...)delegates will get called anyway, and ill have to start a beginBackgroundTask..... to do the notification.
This raises another question iin my head. If i try to update a UIProgressBar in the delegate, isnt there a rule that an app that makes UI updates in the background will get killed instantly?
Is there a way to find if the delegate got called when the app was in the background?
(Forgive me, but im a little inexperienced.)

Comment: Also, I dont want to show any updates as the user  is in the background. I just need to show a progressbar when it is in teh foreground, and support for background downloading.

Comment: I m uploading a file and it stops when going in background, I used the above mentioned line and it failed instantly and server guy told me that your socket has been disconnected with this error:"Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Socket read failed"