# iPhone ASIHTTPRequest how to continue request loading in the background, once the home key is tapped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background, asihttprequest

I'm trying to understand how to use ASIHTTPRequest to initiate a long-running file download from the internet that can be continued if the user switches to other apps using multi-tasking.

So far I was able to keep downloading the file within the app, as the user switches tabs, etc, but once the home key is pressed, the request appears to be cancelled. Is there a way to use the  ASIHTTPRequest or ASINetworkQueue to download files in background?

Here's what I currently have:

```
//the requests are created like this
    self.backgroundMovieDownloader.request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.video.url]];

//the requests are added to this queue
     if (!self.networkQueue) {
                self.networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];
            }

            self.failed = NO;
            [self.networkQueue reset];
            //[self.networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressIndicator];
            [self.networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(videoFetchComplete:)];
            [self.networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(videoFetchFailed:)];
            [self.networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
            [self.networkQueue setDelegate:self];
            [self.networkQueue go];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASIHTTPRequest and background download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967004/asihttprequest-and-background-download)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this line to allow it to run in the background

```
self.backgroundMovieDownloader.request.shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground = YES;
```