# Image corrupted after POST on ftp

Tags: ios, xcode, file-upload, http-post, nsurlrequest

I'm tryin to upload images from my Saved Photos (iPhone 4) using http-post request.
I got uploader.php which works fine moving $_FILES to right place.
But in the end, when image uploaded I see this:

[image: the image i dl from ftp after successful POST]

I've spent hours trying to fix the problem and looking for related questions here but nothing works for me.

```
-(void)sendImage:(UIImage*)image{
    NSString *url = @"http://www.mypage.vv.si/uploader.php";
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                        timeoutInterval:60.0f];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"UVYDTNFMLFUVTTCECELPLCPELCPE";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [theRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    if (imageData)
    {
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Length %d\r\n\r\n", [imageData length] ] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSString *timeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
        timeStr = [timeStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
        NSString *uniqueFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%@.jpg", timeStr];
        NSString *contDispos = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", uniqueFileName];

        [body appendData:[contDispos dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
        [body appendData:imageData];

        [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:body];


        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
        [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
        if (connection) {
            self.infoData = [NSMutableData data];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connection failed");
        }
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"No Data!");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363828/corrupted-image-when-uploading-in-background

Comment: the problem is actual only when i'm trying to dl uploaded images from ftp, but when I display the images thru my html code (<img />) they looks correct. So maybe the problem is in my online ftp browser.